# Bitcoin core doesn’t see transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I’ve created address in bitcoin core from rpc and send some bitcoins on it, but my balance still zero. Transaction exists I’ve checked on blockchain info. Getaddressinfo returns “ismine”: true, but getreceivedbyaddress returns zero

Comment: Are you fully synchronized with the blockchain? You won't see the transaction until you are.

Comment: I use prune mode, the last time I used it, it worked well.  Where can I read about this?

Comment: Pruning has nothing to do with it. What do you see with `getblockchaininfo` RPC?

Comment: `"chain": "main",
  "blocks": 445138,
  "headers": 614383,
  "bestblockhash": "0000000000000000002de7741730df4307a0b07af877fdac1f03b9be9e97da54",
  "difficulty": 310153855703.4333,
  "mediantime": 1482716862,
  "verificationprogress": 0.3696978576853237,
  "initialblockdownload": true,
  "chainwork": "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000034fc10a015a432503589bd",
  "size_on_disk": 533371171,
  "pruned": true,
  "pruneheight": 444665,
  "automatic_pruning": true,
  "prune_target_size": 576716800,
`

Comment: You'll need to wait until blocks == headers. You're about 3 years worth of blocks behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Peter in the comments of your question, you will need to wait until your node has synced with the longest chain. At the time of your comment, you are 169,245 blocks behind which, unless your transaction took place ~3 years ago, will not be known to your node yet. As soon as the block containing your transaction is verified by your node, you will be able to see the transaction.